# Deleted aws kms key so can't able to access s3 objects

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kms

[this is the error pls find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHXUL.png)

I have created a s3 bucket with kms key and uploaded objects after that without knowledge I have deleted the kms key now I can't able to access the bucket objects even the objects are there. It there any possible to recover the objects. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.  If you have the original key material then theoretically you can, but I'm not finding a way to do it.
I'll keep trying and if I find something I will post it here.

Update:
AWS creates ciphertext from metadata of the KMS secondary key. Once the key is deleted the data is unrecoverable. Moreover, access to ciphertext is strictly prohibited for security reasons.